# Why does v-dialog reset another element's visibility toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Been hacking at this for days, hopefully there are some Vuetify wizards around.

**Here's the situation:** I have rendered a set of `v-expansion-panels` and if one of them is expanded, it also shows an arrow button (`display: none` is toggled by clicking on `v-expansion-header`). Upon that button click, my aim is to show a dialog.

**Problem:** Once dialog is prompted with the button click, the button display toggle is reversed. It disappears as soon as you click on the button to prompt a dialog, and appears again once the `v-expansion-panel` is collapsed.

**How it should be:** The arrow button should always be visible as long as the `v-expansion-panel` is expanded, regardless of whether it is clicked to see the dialog or not.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/oNjYxEL)'s a codepen replicating and illustrating the problem.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with using `style` directly on the element.

Use `v-show` instead of toggling the styles by hand:

`<v-btn v-on="on" class="ml-1" width="36px" v-show="expanded[i]">`

Update your data to hold an array for the pannels

```
data () {
 return {
  dialog: false,
  expanded: [false, false, false]
 }
}
```

And update your `toggleMoveUp` method to update `expanded` instead of using HTML ids.

```
toggleMoveup(i) {
 this.$set(this.expanded, i, !this.expanded[i])

 this.show=true;
}
```

Notes:

- You need to use `Vue.set` when updating an array
- You should not rely on HTML ids, if you use your components in more than one place at a time you'll run into multiple ids.

Why didn't your approach work? I'm guessing that vuetify is updating an element's style property, but doesn't take care of retaining already existing values so your `display:none` gets erased.

Comment: What an elegant approach! 
Just one clarification though: in my actual project the array length can vary, so in this case I can not keep track of expand state in data already. I tried to make your solution work with a local dataset and added a computed property `expanded`, but I think I am missing something. I'd really appreciate your thoughts on where I went wrong! https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/dyYOgdM 

Maybe the issue is that toggleMoveup(i) is not able to mutate a computed property?

Comment: computed methods are not reactive. The return value, even if changed, will not update the template and will be visible outside of the calling scope. You need to declare expanded as a variable on your data object. You could add a field named expand on your dataset items and access it something like this data.dataset[i].expanded.

Comment: yes, I thought about that. but considering that the data is coming externally in the end (user feedbacks), I am afraid it won't be feasible to ask the backend to add a datafield just for this one component feature :(

Comment: You don't need to ask the backend for this, nor should you. You can get the data from the backend and then map it by adding a new field to it

Comment: Thank you for the hint! as a beginner I never even thought about that. I tried to tinker with the data mapping here, and made a computed array `itemset` with `expanded:false` property added on each item. Could you perhaps take a look at the toggleMoveup() method? I am not quite sure how to adjust the $set arguments there: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/JjYbxJP

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution a colleague helped with. This also works with any array size (which is more of a real life scenario in dynamic webapps). It implements a `created()` lifecycle hook that adds an `expanded: false` property to each element in the array, which we can use to keep track of the expand state and toggle the button visibility. [Here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/pojRrZP)'s the codepen.

However, in general, it is recommended in this scenario to actually make an independent component `<v-expansion-panels />` and in the parent component actually loop the components. That would solve the state problems on its own already, since each component maintains their own state in their scope.